# How do I move an application from Launchpad into Applications folder?

Tags: mac-appstore, launchpad

I purchased Pixelmator 2 from the Mac App store. The app appeared in Launchpad, but not in my applications folder. The problem is that I don't use Launchpad.

I can't find where Pixelmator is actually installed on my hard disk, and I want to move it into my applications folder.

How do I move it from Launchpad to the Applications folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this:

1. Activate Launchpad
2. Launch the application
3. Click and hold the application's dock icon
4. In the Options menu, choose "Show in Finder"
5. Move the application to the desired destination